how to be removed on all StackExchange forum
(I know this question is off topic here but don't know where to ask it)
I want all my postings from all stackexchange forum to be removed.
My contact information is below:
Basile STARYNKEVITCH           basile@starynkevitch.net
8 rue de la Faïencerie
92340 Bourg-la-Reine           mobile: +33 6 8501 2359
France                         http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/

I would urgently recommend not to include your personal contact details on a publicly-viewable site such as this one [this assumes this is really you posting this, and not someone who hacked the account].

@AdminBee I agree 100% with you, but Basile’s contact information has been publicly available on starynkevitch.net for a long time.

@StephenKitt Ah, ok. I wasn't aware of that.

We can't help. First, what you ask for isn't going to be possible. When you posted here, you agreed to give Stack Overflow (the company) a perpetual license to your content:

[...] any and all content [...] is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you [...]

This means you don't have any legal basis on which to ask that your posts be removed. Now, perhaps SE will choose to do so, but only they can decide so you need to ask this of the company itself. You can use the Contact form for that.

As an aside, I don't quite understand why you have chosen to dox yourself here and share you actual physical address and telephone number, and I strongly urge you to remove them (please flag your post if you would like us to purge the history) as this is unwise and dangerous and not relevant in any way whatsoever here.
